# Codeigniter Dropdown issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i've a problem with Dropdown pop-up.
in my Dropdown there is option "Add New" when i click on "Add New" pop should open..which can not open now !
**Here Is Dropdown's Code**

```
echo form_dropdown('Birth_Certificate_Storage_id['.$key.']', $optionstorage,"",array('class'=>'form-control roleId','id'=>'Birth_Certificate_Storage_id['.$key.']','onchange'=>'addRole(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)'));
```

i have put "onchange" event in dropdown and make function "addRole()"

**addRole() Function**

```
function addRole(val)
{
//alert("test");    
if (val == "ADD NEW") 
{

    $('#RoleModal').modal('show');
    $('#form_role').validate({
     rules: 
    {
      Storage Code: { required: true},
      Storage Location: { required: true},
    },
    messages:
    {
    Storage Code: {required: "This field is Required"},
    Storage Location: {required: "This field is Required"}
    }
}); 
}
```

}
Function isn't working,i can not alert in that function
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**updated:**

The forth parameter of form_dropdown function should be a string not an array, like:

```
echo form_dropdown('Birth_Certificate_Storage_id[' . $key . ']', $optionstorage, "", 'class="form-control roleId" id="Birth_Certificate_Storage_id[' . $key . ']"');
```

If you use jQuery you can bind the change event in your javascript code/file instead of set it inline:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.form-control.roleId').on('change', function () {
        var val = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        if (val == "ADD NEW") {
            $('#RoleModal').modal('show');
            $('#form_role').validate({
                rules   : {
                    'Storage Code'    : {required: true},
                    'Storage Location': {required: true}
                },
                messages: {
                    'Storage Code'    : {required: "This field is Required"},
                    'Storage Location': {required: "This field is Required"}
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Please notice I fixed some problems in your JS!

Comment: issue is in the function bcz in consol this type of error occurs "ReferenceError: addRole is not defined" but i've defined that fuction don't no why this error occurs :)